# Show/Change Work Directory in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Does SQLite have a command which displays what directory I am working in on the command line?

Also, how to change work directory there?

Comment: do you want to do this in command-line sqlite client?

Comment: Anybody? Surely someone knows.

Comment: the sqlite manual http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html does not hint at such a possibility but I suppose you checked it already.

Answer (score 9):

`sqlite3` does have the concept of a current directory (although it is "deferring" to the underlying shell); otherwise it wouldn't have a [`.cd DIRECTORY`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_) command.

To mimic `pwd` you can use:

```
sqlite> .shell pwd
/Users/brad/
```

The syntax is `.shell CMD ARGS...`, which allows you to

> Run `CMD ARGS...` in a system shell

To change the directory, use `.cd`:

```
sqlite> .cd /Users/yourname/directory/
```

The `.cd` command [was added in version  3.20.0](http://docs.w3cub.com/sqlite/changes/) (released 2017-08-01).

Answer (score 7):

`.shell cd` can help you to show the current directory.

For changing the directory, you are gonna need to set it up at the beginning.

Comment: Printing the current working directory is just a side effect of the `cd` command. If you are referring to the unix shell, why don't you suggest the more obvious `pcw` (**p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in addition to `.cd` you can also type `ls` in your terminal to show the directory you're working on and its contents

Comment: the question was how to get that info from SQLite client. Do you answer that specific question?